# How to display snapshot data from Firebase 3 which was working perfectly in Firebase 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

Alright now this was working perfectly with firebase 2 but with the firebase 3 update it appears that how I was getting my snapshot from the console and displaying it on the front end is no longer working. I believe this is because $firebaseArray may not be supported anymore? Or it may not function the same way? My console is showing the error of "Error: Must pass a valid Firebase reference to $firebaseArray (not a string or URL)." Any ideas are greatly appreciated, I have a very simple thread/notification center that utilizes HTML and AngularJS and then a javascript controller, here is my code:

JavaScript:

```
sample.controller("threadCtrl", function($scope, $firebaseArray, $timeout) {

        /* Get Stored Posts */
        var ratesRef = firebase.database().ref('posts');

        ratesRef.on("value", function (snapshot) {
          $timeout(function () {
            update(snapshot);
            console.log(snapshot);
          });
        });

        function update (snapshot) {
          $scope.todos = $firebaseArray(ratesRef);
        };

        /* Add posts */
        $scope.addItem = function writeUserData(userId, name, email) {
          var timestamp = new Date().valueOf()

          firebase.database().ref('posts').push({
            id: timestamp,
            description: $scope.postDescription,
            liked: false
          });

          $scope.postDescription = "";
        };

    });
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Beginning of Middle Column (Notification Center) -->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="height: 90%; border-radius: 10px; margin-left: 2%; margin-right: 2%; text-align: center;">
    <h1>Notification Center</h1>
    <div style="width: 90%; height: 85%; border: 1px solid black; margin: 0px auto; overflow-y: auto; border-radius: 10px;">

         <!-- Beginning of the Card -->
         <div class="card text-xs-center" ng-repeat="item in todos | orderBy:'-id'">

             <a ui-sref="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#postModal" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000; cursor: pointer;">
                 <div class="card-block">
                     <p class="card-text" style="padding-left: 5px; padding-right: 5px; padding-top: 5px;">{{item.description}}</p>
                 </div>
             </a>

             <!-- Line break between notifications -->
             <hr style="width: 50%; color: #aaa;">
             <!-- End of line break -->

         </div>
         <!-- End of the Card -->



     </div>
</div>
<!-- End of Middle Column (Notification Center) -->
```

Like I noted above, this was working perfect with Firebase 2 (only difference is that that the firebase.database()... lines were direct links to the firebase URL). I'd also like to note that adding a post works perfectly. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: The AngularFire version that supports the new 3.x SDK version is not out yet. The code is in Github, it's waiting for some final reviews before it's released.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! This has been driving me nuts for quite a few days, I plan on rolling back to Firebase 2 until this gets resolved.